# How do I make udev rules work?

Tags: udev

I would like to learn udev rules. Here is what I do:

```
victor@X301A1:~$ ls /etc/udev/rules.d/
70-persistent-cd.rules  70-persistent-net.rules  README
```

Then:

```
victor@X301A1:~$ sudo gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/01-my-first-udev.rules
```

My rule:

```
ACTION=="add", RUN+="echo HELLO ! > /home/victor/udev_test_log.txt"
```

After saving the file:

```
 sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
```

I expected that connecting an USB device would write in the file but nothing happens.
Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In RUN you must to put a path to a script. See `man udev`:

> Add a program to the list of programs to be executed for a specific
>              device. This can only be used for very short running tasks. Running
>              an event process for a long period of time may block all further
>              events for this or a dependent device. Long running tasks need to
>              be immediately detached from the event process itself.

For examle, create a new script, let say `hello.sh` in `/lib/udev` with `sudo -H gedit /lib/udev/hello.sh` and put next lines inside:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo HELLO ! > /home/<username>/udev_test_log.txt
```

Change `<username>` with your user name. Save the file, close it and make it executable with:

```
chmod +x /lib/udev/hello.sh
```

Add a new rule in your `/etc/udev/rules.d/01-my-first-udev.rules` file like this:

```
ACTION=="add", RUN+="/lib/udev/hello.sh"
```

Comment: I tried with my mouse but nothing happens. How can I "debug" this ?

Comment: @VictorL I edited my answer. Is tested, so it should work.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, I couldn't get a reference for this; But It's something got by Try  & Error.

- `udev` requires the full path of script/program/file used either in `PROGRAM`, `TEST`, `RUN` or `IMPORT`.
- `udev` doesn't support redirection operations.
- `udev` can handle command with arguments.
- `udev` has variable substitution.

So you can write multifunction script (not just blind/single task script :) ), Example that sure it works for me:

```
KERNEL=="2-1.2:1.[0-9]*", DRIVER!="usb-storage", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo -n %k,%p > /home/sneetsher/Desktop/%n.txt'"
```

- `/bin/sh` absolute path
- `>` redirection is handled inside shell
- `-c '...'` 2 command arguments
- `%k`, `%p`, `%n` udev variables (device kernel name, device path, device number)

So for your case:

```
ACTION=="add", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo HELLO ! > /home/victor/udev_test_log.txt'"
```