# udev script does not start when event happen

Tags: udev

I was annoyed that every time I connect my hdmi cable I need to manually change the sound setting.

I started looking into udev rules, what I came out with are these two files:

`/etc/udev/rules.d/99-hdmi_sound.rules`

```
SUBSYSTEM=="drm", RUN+="/lib/udev/hdmi_sound_toggle.sh"
```

`/lib/udev/hdmi_sound_toggle.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

HDMI_STATUS=`cat /sys/class/drm/card0/*HDMI*/status`
if [ $HDMI_STATUS = "connected" ]
then
    sudo -u root pactl set-card-profile 0 output:hdmi-stereo
else
    sudo -u root pactl set-card-profile 0 output:analog-stereo
fi
```

When I'm running hdmi_sound_toggle.sh in the terminal, it works. It does not auto-run, though.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Here is [Set HDMI sound output automatically on connect/disconnect](http://askubuntu.com/questions/263248/set-hdmi-sound-output-automatically-on-connect-disconnect) and [Switching to HDMI Audio when HDMI is plugged into a laptop (14.04)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/458194/switching-to-hdmi-audio-when-hdmi-is-plugged-into-a-laptop-14-04)

Comment: I used those answers to get to my current state. Again, because the script works when I run it from the terminal, I'm pretty sure that the problem is in the udev rule.

Comment: It can be related to user who runs script. Take a look at [Set HDMI sound output automatically on connect/disconnect](http://askubuntu.com/questions/263248/set-hdmi-sound-output-automatically-on-connect-disconnect) pactl is runned with sudo -u $user. When you run this script manually, script run with your privilege, while when it auto-run (I guess) user should be root.

Comment: changed the script, still doesn't auto-run...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reloading udev? It should recognise new rules automatically, but maybe it didn't...

`sudo udevadm control --reload-rules ; sudo udevadm trigger`

Comment: I tried.. doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

- Try rename it to `99-hdmi_sound.rules` (with 2 digits only)
- & use `RUN` instead and omit `ACTION`

  ```
  SUBSYSTEM=="drm", RUN+="/lib/udev/hdmi_sound_toggle.sh"
  ```
- It could be an environment problem (not same user, or undeclared `env` variables). Try adding some `echo` or `touch` commands to trace your script. Example:

  ```
  echo `date --rfc-3339='ns'` START >> /home/<your-username>/Desktop/udev_test_log.txt
  ```

  Put one in beginning, end, inside `if`, `else` ...

Comment: Tried, doesn't work... updated the question

Comment: ok, the rule actually working.
the `pactl` cmd gives the error: `Connection failure: Connection refused
pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused`

Comment: @guy, try `sudo -u yourusername pactl ...`

Comment: tried... the error changed to `Failure: No such entity`
the updated line:
`sudo -u guy pactl set-card-profile 0 output:hdmi-stereo 2>> /home/guy/Desktop/udev_then_log.txt`.
just checked - still work when I call the script from terminal

Comment: sorry, double checked and it doesn't work manually, I will go over the steps and tell you when it stopped to work.

Comment: ok, still working manually. didn't work because of writing the log there was needed root permission (tried without writing the log and worked).

Comment: Does it work if you switch to root, `su -` then run it?

Comment: yes, when I run from terminal after changing to root user