# Conditonal in xorg.conf?

Tags: xorg, synaptics

I have a laptop with a touchpad with physical buttons. The problem is that the physical buttons are part of the touchpad, so the cursor moves when you press them. Basically, what I want to do is get the equivalent of

```
if (touchpressure() > arbitrary_threshold && isinbottomfourthoftouchpad())
    disabletouchinbottomfourthoftouchpad();
```

in /etc/X11/xorg.conf. Is this solvable through easy scripting, or through something far more involved?

For those interested, my laptop is an HP Pavilion dv6t.

Answer (score 0):

No.

xorg.conf is just a plain text file that is parsed (ie. the lines in it are read by a script and the script sets all the parameters, options and what else is valid in xorg.conf) so no, you can not use conditions. That line you want included would just be ignored or it would error out since the xorg subsystem does not understand it.

You could do this with a udev rule ([Writing udev rules](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html) and [How do I make udev rules work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/297412/how-do-i-make-udev-rules-work) will get you started).