# Simple udev rule doesn't work on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: command-line, bash, usb, scripts, udev

Can't get what's wrong with my udev rule and bash script. I want to make simple test on usb device insertion.

This is my rule `/etc/udev/rules.d/90-usb.rules`:

`ACTION=="add", RUN+="/home/mike/notification.sh"`

And this is my script `/home/mike/notification.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'message:Hello!' | zenity --notification --listen
```

Just from terminal this command works fine.

Comment: did you make your script executable by `chmod +x /home/mike/notification.sh` ?

Comment: Yes, I did. I can run it from terminal like this `/home/mike/notification.sh` and it works, but with udev it doesn't.

Comment: Try radu's  answer here https://askubuntu.com/questions/297412/how-do-i-make-udev-rules-work

Comment: Why? I added this rule `ACTION=="add", RUN+="/home/mike/notification.sh"`, so it should trigger the command on **add** event. Correct me if i wrong, please.

Comment: place your script in `/lib/udev`

Comment: I think problem stems from `udev` redirection as @user.dz suggested in the above link.

Comment: try it like `ACTION=="add", RUN+="/bin/sh /home/mike/notification.sh"`